# Uploading binary files. Encoding problems

Tags: python, encoding, urllib2

I want to send a file with binary data to server using urllib2:

```
def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
    LIMIT = '----------lImIt_of_THE_fIle_eW_$'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    L = []
    for (key, value) in fields:
        L.append('--' + LIMIT)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        L.append('')
        L.append(str(value))
    for (key, filename, value) in files:
        L.append('--' + LIMIT)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key,    str(filename)))
        L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    L.append('--' + LIMIT + '--')
    L.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(L)
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % LIMIT
    return content_type, body
```

Using:

```
    f = open(filePath, "rb")
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata([("param1",self.param1)], [("myfile", self.name, f.read())])
    request = urllib2.Request(url, body)
    request.add_header('Content-type', content_type)
    request.add_header('Content-length', str(len(body)))
    response =  urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

If file contain only ascii symbols than all ok. But if file contains binary data, i have error at last string of code:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 271: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to encode body? File must be same at the server as on client

Comment: This task would be a lot easier with the [`requests` library](http://python-requests.org), if that is an option for you.

Comment: Heh. I started solve my task with `urllib2`, and wanted to finish it with this library. But maybe need to try and `requests`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates you are mixing Unicode data and byte strings.

Your file data consists of only byte strings, which means your *other* POST values (the keys and values in `fields`) or the filenames use unicode values. Encode all those values to byte strings first.

Comment: I check with debugger that the result of `encode_multipart_formdata` is string of bytes. And problems is in code from `urllib2` which concatenate unicode message and my string body

Comment: @user1173794: Then your next stop should be seeing what headers you pass to `urllib2`. The library *by itself* will never use Unicode. You may want to share your full traceback so we can help diagnose.

Comment: I debug all code and find that url, which i pass to request is in unicode. This is my mistake.